# wp_enqueue_script or wp_head

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, plugins

Many plugins that I have downloaded use the wp_head action hook to add JavaScript to the
header, I have always used the wp_enqueue_script() to enter JS/Ajax inside  tags. What is the difference? And is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation page for WP actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) says that they are  related.

> **wp_head**
> Runs when the template calls the wp_head function. This hook is generally placed near the top of a page template between `<head>` and `</head>`. This hook does not take any parameters.
>
> **wp_print_scripts**
> Runs just before WordPress prints registered JavaScript scripts into the page header.

Therefore, if you wish to emit a script block `<script>....</script>`, you could use either. `wp_print_scripts` seems appropriate if you'd like your script block to immediately precede the script blocks for registered script references.

Comment: Many thanks. I searched for the documentation and I didn't return anything. Thank you very much for clearing this up for me. I suppose that many plugin authors fail to know the difference, and that is perhaps the reason with the inconsistency with the code that I have seen.

Answer (score 3):

#### The proper action to hook into when enqueueing scrips is `wp_enqueue_scripts`

There is no documentation for this hook yet see [admin_enque_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts), wp_enqueue_scripts is basically the same hook except that it only runs on the front end.

If you use the wp_print_scripts hook your scripts will also be added to the admin.

See also the [dev blog post](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/) for more info.